# Combining two vectors (filling up containers with the contents of several cans)

Tags: clojure

I have two vectors

```
(def container [{:no 1 :volume 10} {:no 2 :volume 20}])
(def cans [{:no 1 :volume 2} {:no 2 :volume 8} {:no 1 :volume 5} {:no 2 :volume 8}])
```

I'd like to fill up the containers with the cans so as to return something like this:

```
[{:no 1 :volume 10
  :cans [{:no 1 :volume 2} {:no 2 :volume 8}]}
 {:no 2 :volume 20
  :cans [{:no 1 :volume 5} {:no 2 :volume 8}]}]
```

thereby keeping track of which can went into which container. I started by using reduce but cannot get my head around how to do this without using a mutating store for holding the remaining cans. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

By fill up, i meant pack in as many cans in the first container until it's full or as near as (the sum of the can's volumes not exceeding that of the container's volume), then start filling up the second container until it's full or as near as, and so on.

Comment: those `def` calls are not valid - I assume you wanted container and cans to be vectors or lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to use a mutating store for the remaining cans, because reduce takes a sequence as an argument, and reduces over the accumulating function, calling it on each element of the sequence.

In the following, I separate the containers into filled / not yet filled, and insert each can into the container in which it will be the tightest fit (this tends to optimize packing).

```
user> (def container [{:no 1 :volume 10} {:no 2 :volume 20}])
#'user/container
user> (def cans [{:no 1 :volume 2} {:no 2 :volume 8} {:no 1 :volume 5} {:no 2 :volume 8}])
#'user/cans
user> 
(def containerized
  (let [containers (map #(assoc % :capacity (:volume %) :cans []) container)
        insert (fn [container can]
                 (-> container
                     (update-in [:capacity] - (:volume can))
                     (update-in [:cans] conj can)))
        accumulator (fn [[filled filling] can]
                      (let [[non-fits [picked & unpicked]]
                            (split-with #(< (:capacity %)
                                            (:volume can))
                                        (sort-by :capacity filling))
                           picked (insert picked can)
                           still-filling (concat non-fits unpicked)]
                        (if (<= (:capacity picked) 0)
                          [(conj filled picked) still-filling]
                          [filled (conj still-filling picked)])))
        filled (reduce accumulator
                       [[] containers]
                       cans)]
    (map #(dissoc % :capacity) (apply concat filled))))

#'user/containerized
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint containerized)
({:cans [{:volume 2, :no 1} {:volume 8, :no 2}], :volume 10, :no 1}
 {:cans [{:volume 5, :no 1} {:volume 8, :no 2}], :volume 20, :no 2})
nil
```

Comment: Ah sorry. By fill up, i meant pack in as many cans in the first container until it's full or as near as, then start filling up the second container until it's full or as near as, and so on. I've updated the question.

Comment: It's a bit more complex with the packing logic, and could probably be clearer with some decomposition into helper functions, but it works.

Comment: rereading the question - do you prefer filling first container completely before using the second, or would it be preferable to get an optimal packing? these are different tasks, and I may have wrongly assumed the latter